# Resource Controller in edit not having data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

Link to edit

```
<a href="/dashboard/rejected/{{ $reject->id }}/edit" class="badge bg-danger">{{ $reject->status }}</a>
```

Route

```
Route::resource('/dashboard/rejected', RejectController::class);
```

Controller

```
public function edit(Reject $reject)
{
    dd($reject);
    return view('dashboard.reject.edit',[
        'tittle' => 'Reject Stock',
        'reject' => $reject
    ]);
}
```

`$reject` on my controller was not able to retrieve data

```
GET|HEAD dashboard/rejected/{rejected}/edit rejected.edit›RejectController@edit
```

Comment: your route parameter is named `rejected` not `reject` ... so `Reject $reject` is method injection, not implicit model binding ... so you are ending up with a new non-existing instance of `Reject`

Comment: @lagbox thankyouu so much!

Comment: On your route you add parameter as @lagbox mentioned

Route::get('/dashboard/rejected/{id}', [RejectController::class, 'edit'])->name('edit');
I am not sure if my solution is correct, you may want to test it.

Answer (score -1):

I advise you to use the function **route()** to refer to your path instead of hard typing it.
you can do:

```
<a href="route('dashboard.reject.edit', $reject->id)" class="badge bg-danger">{{ $reject->status }}</a>
```

then you should change the invoked function argument to be

```
public function edit(string $reject_id)
{
    dd($reject_id);
    return view('dashboard.reject.edit',[
        'tittle' => 'Reject Stock',
        'reject' => Reject::find($reject_id)
    ]);
}
```

finaly, your route name should be as following:

```
Route::resource('dashboard.rejected', RejectController::class);
```

this is a more 'elegent' way to code, hope you find this useful.

Comment: Do you know why when I go to `edit`, the data from the ID is empty?

Answer (score -1):

When you use slash in resource , it will also be in route binding, so you should'n use it in resource , you can use `dashboard-rejected` in route and
`$dashboard_rejected` as param in controller , and you will get data.

on a note :
put the noun in the plural in the route and the singular in the parameter,

example:

```
/user-posts , $userPost

/posts , $post
```

You also can [customize](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic) route binding.